# Youtube iframe API fires first after hitting F5

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, ruby-on-rails-5

This is my html:

```
<% provide(:title, "Test") %>

<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'dVVZaZ8yO6o',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

</script>
```

The video starts if I call it for the first time but if I change the route and come back, it does not work anymore until I hit F5. After that the same problem: if route is changed it will work first after hitting F5. I tried to check if maybe the local and server behavior is maybe simply inconsistent but that is not the case.

Edit:

The html above is inside of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= render "layouts/shim" %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render "layouts/header" %>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="notifications">
        <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
          <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type%>"><%= message %></div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.developement? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

shim:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

header and footer is just a collection of links, don't think it is important here.

I am using Win7 Home Premium and firefox.

Comment: can't reproduce that effect in chrome, IE or Firefox .. what browser are u using? OS? Can you show the whole code of the page (if this is not all)?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my post now.

Comment: Ok, I just realized that I can fix this problem by removing <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> but that is not really a great solution since then (for example) all my dropdown menus don't work anymore.  Can I somehow change this line without breaking the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, problem solved. Apparently youtube API is not a big fan of turbolinks. After removing those from assets/javascripts/application.js, everything works fine again.